# Is there a way to improve speed with for loops

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I am needing to POST a series of XML elements (could be a varying amount per call).  I am using Requests v2.25.1 on Python 3.9.1.  While my solution works, it is taking roughly 27 seconds to execute although the requests module shows an `r.elapsed` of under 1 second to complete.  Things I have validated:

- `r.text` encoding issues do not exist
- header information is correct
- creating `requests.Session()` does not improve response time

When running Postman I am also seeing results in under 1 second.  I have isolated this issue to the `for loop` I am running.  Data is pulled from SQL, stored as a variable then the for loop processes this and runs in my XML request.

My question is if my following code is best practice or if there is a more 'pythonian' way of completing what I am looking to accomplish?  Any guidance is appreciated.

```
    skill_id=[]
    agent_state=[]
    agent_name=[]

    for db_users in db_results:
       skill_id.append(db_users[0])
       agent_state.append(db_users[1])
       agent_name.append(db_users[2])
    if db_users[1] == 'NOT_READY':
       try:
            cursor.execute(sqlskillgroup)
            skillgroups = []
            for sg_query_result in cursor.fetchall():
                sg = sg_query_result[0]
                skillgroups.append(sg)

    except pyodbc.Error as e:
            print("Error retreiving skill group information from database.")
            quit()

    finally:
        connect.close()
    icm_url = "https://url_of_post"
    xmlfile = open('skill_remove.xml', 'r')
    body = xmlfile.read()
    icm_header = {
           'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
           'Authorization': 'Basic Q2hhZF9NZXllckBhamcuY29tOmNpc2Nv',
           'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=0C8456E3901DF7A3A0862E17FD50547D'
           }

    for sgid in skillgroups:
        r = requests.request("POST",icm_url, headers = icm_header,
            data = body.format(agent = str(skill_id[0]), skill_urls = '<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/skillgroup/' + str(sgid) + '</refURL>',),
            verify = r"CAchain.pem",
            cert = (r"cert.cer", r"cert.key"),
            )

    print(r.text)
    print(r.elapsed)
```

Comment: Why do you have three lists - just have one list that holds all 3 items.

That last for loop can be quicker if you pre-build some of the data items (such as the body maybe'. - it is difffiult to see though exactly what the issue is ...

Comment: Is the identation of `if db_users[1] == 'NOT_READY':` OK?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Not sure how I could combine all list items into 1 and call them individually.  The body is for the most part created in an external file and I am passing the 'agent' and 'sgid' values into that file to POST.

Comment: @Ivan - can you clarify?  If you meant indentation, all of that is formatted correctly in my script.

Comment: How many list items are there in skill groups? Printing ```r.elapsed``` will only show you the latest request elapsed time, not cumulative. If you have many requests to make you really should look into asyncio. The problem you run into web servers is the latency between each subsequent request where your machine is idle, waiting for messages to go back and forth

Comment: @Chad - instead of 3 lists you have one list (called agent_data for example) where each entry is a 3-tuple (with skill_id, agent_state, agent_name) - you can then access them using `agent_data[index][0]` will be the skill_id of that agent;, `agent_data[index][1]` will be the agent_state of that agent.

Comment: @Chad Ok! i was wonderinf if that line made part of the loop

Comment: @el_oso There is only a single SQL column pulled but there will eventually be a couple thousand entries.  There are currently 50 loaded for testing.  I will also take a look at asyncio.  Thanks for pointing me to that, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are timing the elapsed time of last request in the loop. You can calculate the total elapsed time by moving `r.elapsed` into the loop and summing each request, or by adding to a running total in the loop and printing at the end.

```py
total_elapsed = 0
   for sgid in skillgroups:
    r = requests.request("POST",icm_url, headers = icm_header,
            data = body.format(agent = str(skill_id[0]), skill_urls = '<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/skillgroup/' + str(sgid) + '</refURL>',),
            verify = r"CAchain.pem",
            cert = (r"cert.cer", r"cert.key"),
            )
    total_elapsed += r.elapsed
```

basic asyncio and aiohttp implementation

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def post_request(session, url):
    async with session.post() as request: #add your request headers, certificate etc
        await request.status

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: # use client session to auto close at the end
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            t = asyncio.create_task(post_request(session, url)) #create a number of tasks to run concurrently
            tasks.append(t)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks) # wait for all tasks to finish before close the session

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Having issues getting aiohttp to post a file but it looks like this may be a viable solution.  Thanks for the help everyone.